# В чём разница между допускать и пускать?

Tags: значения

В чём разница между **"допускать"** и **"пускать"**?

Answer (score 4):

Допускать - предоставлять доступ (access) к чему-либо или позволять чему-либо произойти
Пускать - позволять кому-нибудь зайти внутрь (let in), либо синоним слова "запускать" (to start up)

Answer (score 1):

Да это очень многозначные слова, аж глаза разбегаются от обилия значений. Множества значений этих слов различаются, хотя и частично совпадают. Например:

> Допускать до игры = пускать играть = позволять играть
>
> Допускать, что ... = Делать предположение, что ...
>
> Этого нельзя допускать = Нельзя позволить этому случиться
>
> Пускать мыльные пузыри = Надувать мыльные пузыри и давать им улетать
>
> Пускай он сделает это = Не надо ему мешать сделать это
>
> Пускать на самотёк = Не вмешиваться, позволять происходить естественным образом
>
> Пускать автомобили в центр города = Позволять автомобилям въезжать в центр города
>
> Растение пустило корни = У растения начал рaсти или пророс корень

Короче, это многозначные слова с частично пересекающимися спектрами значений, и надо еще аккуратно обращаться с управлениями, они разные - напр., как я написала выше, допускать до игры = пускать играть.

Answer (score 1):

Допускать означает предоставлять доступ, допустим на экзамен. 
Пускать это напрямую разрешить вход, допустим в клуб после предъявления пропуска.

Answer (score 0):

(Я подразумеваю, что автор вопроса имеет трудности с конкретным значением слова **пускать/пустить**: "*давать физический, пространственный доступ кому-либо*". В этом значении оно пересекается по смыслу с глаголом **допускать/допустить**.)

**Допустить** - более формальный либо абстрактный вариант. Он означает:

- то же, что и **пустить**, но в более серьезной административной форме;
- то же, что и **пустить**, но без указания конкретного времени или совершения факта допуска;
- допуск в абстрактном смысле, не обязательно физический или пространственный

**Пустить** - более обыденный, неформальный либо более конкретный.

Примеры степени формальности:

- **Журналиста допустили в зал совещания** (может использоваться в официальной, пафосной речи)
- **Дворник пустил в комнату кошку** (обыденная ситуация, в которой использование "**допустить**" выглядит глумливо и нецелесообразно, как в "**дворник устроил для кошки званый ужин**")

Примеры общего/конкретного использования:

- **Сотрудникам запрещен доступ в кабинет №31** (официальное положение, регламент, общее правило без конкретных лиц/дат/случаев)
- **Охранника уволили за то, что он пустил незнакомого человека в кабинет №31** (конкретный случай нарушения регламента)
- **Охранник уволен за нерегламентированный допуск постороннего лица** (тот же конкретный случай, но описанный более формальным, сухим языком)
- **Журналиста не пустили в зал несмотря на наличие официального допуска** (факт недопущения журналиста - конкретный случай; допуск - официальный документ, устанавливающий *общее* право посещения без указания на конкретный случай; если журналист вообще не придет, его не смогут пустить, хотя у него есть допуск *в принципе*, как право)

Примеры абстрактного/буквального использования:

- **Студента допустили к экзаменам** (экзамен может проходить удаленно; имел место запрет на *участие* в мероприятиях - допуск снял запрет на абстрактное участие; вероятно, студент не воспользуется полученной возможностью)
- **Студента не пустили на экзамен по алгебре** (студент пытался совершить что-то конкретное, войти в аудиторию, в которой проходит экзамен; кем-то совершенно конкретное силовое действие по удержанию и недопущению в аудиторию; либо он спрашивал разрешение, но ему отказали на словах - в конкретной беседе)
- **Уровень нравов будет неизбежно падать, если допустить на идеологическом уровне саму мысль об исключительном статусе интересов личности** (философский спор о допущении/недопущении образа мышления)
- **Пусти мою руку, негодяй, или я устрою скандал** (кто-то физически удерживает говорящего)